tuya device query with python TuyaOpenAPI, missing sign
I have tried to use tinytuya to control my devices with python but my devices are only partially found.
I have switched to use from the tuya_connector library TuyaOpenAPI.
I have set up a project in the tuya cloud and can query my devices state with e.g.
response = openapi.get("/v1.0/iot-03/devices/{}".format(DEVICE_ID))
trying to get energy consumption with a similar query I get error 1004, missing sign.
I found a lot of information about creating a sign on the tuya pages but I can't figure out, how to make it work with my get request and so far havent been able to find an example how to do that with python.
